# How do you set two parent bones into one child bone?

Tags: bones, parent

I've been trying to set up an IK bone on my foot bone, but every time I set my foot bone as its active bone, the foot bone disconnects from the lower leg bone parent, and sets the IK bone as its parent, though in 'keep offset' mode. This is in version 2.7

Comment: Could you add an image for clarity? :)